# window.document in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, popup

I have this js to show a popup:

oauthpopup.js:

```
popup.show = function(options) {
  this.destination_ = options.destination;
  this.windowOptions_ = options.windowOptions;
  this.closeCallback_ = options.closeCallback;
  this.win_ = null;
  this.win_ = window.open(this.destination_, "_blank", this.windowOptions_);
  if (this.win_) {
    // Poll every 100ms to check if the window has been closed
    var self = this;
    var closure = function() {
      self.checkClosed_(); 
    };
    this.timer_ = window.setInterval(closure, 100);
  }
  return false;
};

popup.checkClosed_ = function() {
  if ((!this.win_) || this.win_.closed) {
    this.handleApproval_();
  }
};

popup.handleApproval_ = function() {
  if (this.timer_) {
    window.clearInterval(this.timer_);
    this.timer_ = null;
  }
  if (this.win_) {
    this.win_.close();
    //this.win_ = null;
  }
  try {
    console.log(this.win_.document);
    if (this.win_.document.scripts[0].innerHTML === 'window.close();') {
      this.closeCallback_();
    };
  } catch (ex) { }
  this.win_ = null;
  return false;
};
```

page script

```
popup.show({destination: '/auth/' + channel, windowOptions: 'location=0,status=0',
    closeCallback:function() {
      switchView(divToShow);
    }
  });

function switchView(divtoShow) {
  $("#" + divtoShow).addClass("hidden");
  $("#" + divtoShow).removeClass("hidden");    
};
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE this line: this.win_.document.scripts[0].innerHTML doesn't works, I put this in a alert() but nothing happens.

EDIT:
The script tag 'window.close();' is rendered from rails controller in a html page.
The html page close the popup when is rendered, the popup is for twitter and google authentication.
How I can execute the callback after the page is rendered and it is closed?

Comment: looking for code in a script tag to decide what to do ಠ_ಠ

Comment: The usual questions: What have you tried?  What were the results? What exactly is your question.

That said, there are a number of issues here, starting with `handleApproval` only being called if `win_` is undefined or closed.  I.e. *Of course* its going to barf if you try to access a property like `document` or `document.scripts`(!) - the window went away. There's no reason to expect any of it's contents to still be usable.